# Fixed effects in linear model

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am fitting a linear model on some panel data

$$y_{it} = \sigma_{cr} + x_{it}^\top\beta + \mu_i + \delta_t+ \epsilon_{it}$$

where $\mu_i$ is individual fixed effect (in the sense used in econometrics) $\delta_t$ are time dummies and $\sigma_{cr}$ is a dummy for area of work and area of residence of individual $i$ at time $t$.

So $c = c(i,t)$ where $c(i,t)$ is the area of individual i in time t.
So $r = r(i,t)$ where $r(i,t)$ is the area of individual i in time t.

The places of work and the places of residence are defined as political municipalities. Assume that the median number in each $(c,r)$-group at a given time $t_0$ is is around 5000 measuring group size as $\#\{i\lvert c(i,t_0)=c,r(i,t_0)=r \}$.

The dummies $\sigma_{cr}$ are only identified by individuals who change either area of residence or area of work. Still I am a bit concerned about the empirical identification. Are there any checks I should/could do to investigate this?

Comment: So $\sigma_{cr}$ could have index $_{it}$ for completeness?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Just so that your setting is clear: is it possible (or not) that several people have the same area of work and home at a given time?

Comment: yes that is correct